# I have two date textboxes in asp.net and I want to find number of days

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two textbox dates in asp.net and I am using vb.net.  I want to find number of days between these two dates provided that all months are thirty days long.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a code writing service; You need to show some effort on your problem...and ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I did a small app that compares two dates to see how many days between those dates that's what I think you where asking.

[APP THAT COMPARES TO DATES IN TEXTBOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2R1R.jpg)

This is the code from the botton the difference btw days will be displayed in the text Txtdifbtwdays

```
    Private Sub btncompare_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncompare.Click
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim date2 As Date
    Dim countdays As Integer
    Dim day1 As Integer
    Dim day2 As Integer

    date1 = Me.Txtdate1.Text.ToString
    date2 = Me.Txtdate2.Text.ToString
    Dim getdays As Integer
    getdays = date2.Subtract(date1).TotalDays
    Me.Txtdifbtwdays.Text = getdays


End Sub
```

ounce you have the difference in days btw dates you can add the conditions you want

```
if getdays >30 then
'''do this 
else
''''do this
end if
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but my question is i want all months are 30 when calculated period even february is 30 and the months that equal 31 count it 30 for example from 15/02/2017 to 30/03/2017 number of days 45